# Vue.js - Vuetify : Unknown custom element: [ ... ] - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm getting this error for each html tag of Vuetify.
I installed Vuetify using

```
npm install --save-dev vuetify
```

In my main.js I have :

```
const Vue = require("vue");
const Vuetify = require("vuetify");
const tracksList = require("./track-list.vue");

Vue.use(Vuetify);

trackList = new Vue({el: "#track-list", template: "<tracksList/>", components: {tracksList}});
```

The file track-list.vue is :

```
<template src="../templates/track-list-component.html"></template>
<script src="./track-list.js"></script>
```

In my template track-list-component.html, here is the part which uses Vuetify :

```
<div class="track-name-row"
                 v-on:click="expandTrack(project.structure.tracks.indexOf(track))"
                 @contextmenu="show">
                <li class="track-color-viewer"></li>
                <span>{{"Track "+project.structure.tracks.indexOf(track)}}</span>
                <img class="item-view" src="../assets/img/ic_view.svg" alt="view">
            </div>

            <v-menu offset-y v-model="showMenu" :position-absolutely="true" :position-x="x" :position-y="y">
                <v-list>
                    <v-list-tile>
                        <v-list-tile-title>test</v-list-tile-title>
                    </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
```

The track-list.js is a simple Vue component :

```
module.exports = {
    name: "track-list",
    components: {
            [ ... ]
    },

    data() {
        return {
               [ ... ]
        };
    }
}
```

For importing Vuetify, is there other things to do than installing Vuetify with npm and using Vue.use(Vuetify) in main.js? I am a bit lost and sad, this lib seems to be really great.

Comment: Your `main.js` looks ok, and no, there's no additional steps to take. This should work.

Comment: What the name custom element that causes error?

Comment: @Alfa v-menu v-list v-list-tile v-list-tile-title .

Comment: Change `const Vuetify = require("vuetify")` to `const Vuetify = require("vuetify").default` and see if it works.

Comment: It worked ! Have you an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    name: "track-list",
    components: {
        [ ... ]
    },
    data() {
        return {
           [ ... ]
        };
    }
 }
```

Should be

```
module.exports = {
    name: "track-list",
    components: {
        componentName
    },
    data() {
        return {
           variableName: ''
        };
    }
 }
```

Components should include  all the custom components you are using.(componentName in example). Remove the components part if you are not using any,

Data should include all the variables you are using for that component(variableName in example).

Comment: I added "const vuetify = require("vuetify");" at the beginning of my component and "vuetify" in the components list. Still not functioning.

Comment: You have already included the vuetify component. Just remove the components section.

Comment: the code I put is a simplified one, I already have a component (draggable) . So I cannot remove the components section, just removed what I just added :)

Comment: Can you share you components code? and import lines if possible.